# Unit testing with Arquillian , no default container

Tags: unit-testing, jboss, jboss-arquillian

I get the following Arquillian error : **org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.deployment.ValidationException: DeploymentScenario contains a target (*DEFAULT*) not matching any defined Container in the registry.
Please include at least 1 Deployable Container on your Classpath.**

This are my camel routes class

@Singleton
public class App extends RouteBuilder {

```
@Inject
private CamelContext context;

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    from("file://src/main/resources/temp2/").routeId("camelmarian")
            .onException(WrongFileException.class)
            .handled(true)
            .process(new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("Wrong File Name " + exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileName"));
                    exchange.getIn().setBody("Wrong extension");
                }
            })
            .id("mockerror")
            .end()
            .choice()
            .when(header("CamelFileName").regex("data[0-9]*.xml"))
            .process(new XmlProcessor())
            .id("mockxml")
            //.to("mock:xml")
            .when(header("CamelFileName").regex("data[0-9]*.csv"))
            .process(new CsvProcessor())
            // .to("mock:csv")
            .id("mockcsv")
            .when(header("CamelFileName").regex("data[0-9]*.txt"))
            .process(new TextProcessor())
            //.to("mock:txt")
            .id("mocktext")
            .otherwise()
            .throwException(new WrongFileException("Wrong file extension"));

}
```

}

This is the class with endpoints which i am going to mock:

@Singleton
public class CamelContextSetup {

```
@Inject
private CamelContext camelContext;

private MockEndpoint afterCSV;

private MockEndpoint afterXML;

private MockEndpoint afterTXT;

private MockEndpoint afterError;

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {

    afterCSV = new MockEndpoint("mockCSV");
    afterXML = new MockEndpoint("mockXML");
    afterTXT = new MockEndpoint("mockTXT");
    afterError = new MockEndpoint("mockError");

    camelContext.getRouteDefinition("camelmarian").adviceWith(((ModelCamelContext) camelContext), new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            weaveById("mockcsv").after().to(afterCSV);
        }
    });

    camelContext.getRouteDefinition("camelmarian").adviceWith(((ModelCamelContext) camelContext), new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            weaveById("mockxml").after().to(afterXML);
        }
    });

    camelContext.getRouteDefinition("camelmarian").adviceWith(((ModelCamelContext) camelContext), new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            weaveById("mocktext").after().to(afterTXT);
        }
    });

    camelContext.getRouteDefinition("camelmarian").adviceWith(((ModelCamelContext) camelContext), new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            weaveById("mockerror").after().to(afterError);
        }
    });

    camelContext.start();

}

@After
public void destroy() {
    afterCSV.reset();
    afterError.reset();
    afterTXT.reset();
    afterCSV.reset();
}

@PreDestroy
public void stopContext() throws Exception {
    camelContext.stop();
}

public MockEndpoint getAfterCSV() {
    return afterCSV;
}

public MockEndpoint getAfterXML() {
    return afterXML;
}

public MockEndpoint getAfterTXT() {
    return afterTXT;
}

public MockEndpoint getAfterError() {
    return afterError;
}
```

}

This are the unit tests . When i run them i get that error

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class TestFiles extends CamelTestSupport {

```
@Inject
CamelContextSetup camelContextSetup;


@Before
public void before() throws Exception {
    camelContextSetup.setup();
}

@After
public void after() {
    camelContextSetup.destroy();
}

@Deployment(testable = false)
public static Archive<?> createArchive() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
                .addClass(App.class)
                .addClass(CamelContextSetup.class);
}

@Test
public void testReceived() throws InterruptedException {

    File tempFile = new File("src/main/resources/temp/data.xml");
    if (tempFile.renameTo(new File("src/main/resources/temp2/" + tempFile.getName())))
        System.out.println("failed to move file");
    else {
        camelContextSetup.getAfterXML().expectedMessageCount(1);
        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
    }
}

@Test
public void testError() throws InterruptedException {
    File tempFile = new File("src/main/resources/temp/data4.pl");
    if (tempFile.renameTo(new File("src/main/resources/temp2/" + tempFile.getName())))
        System.out.println("failed to move file");
    else {
        camelContextSetup.getAfterError().expectedMessageCount(1);
        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is your code attempt that produced this error? Please try to make your case reproducible.

Comment: I uploaded my code .

Comment: Great! There seems to be indentation issues with your code, and please keep only the relevant snippet of it so folks don't have to run the whole thing, but only the required part.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add some dependencies in your pom. It would look like that:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.CR9</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.5.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Source: http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started_pt/